# Plotting a histogram using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

I have extracted some values (in array) from a data set in csv format and I am supposed to plot 2 histograms: one entry with rain, one without. Can anyone help me and explain to me how can I utilise the values? Thanks.

```
raining = df[df.rain ==1][['ENTRIESn_hourly']].values
notraining = df[df.rain ==0][['ENTRIESn_hourly']].values
df.hist('ENTRIESn_hourly')
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: @JulienSpronck I want to plot 2 graphs, one entry with only rainy values and one sentry with only non rainy values and the one I currently have does not take into account whether it is raining or not

Comment: you can do something like `df.plot()`. Play around with that. You can plot multiple dataframes (multiple columns), and probably the start of the solution here

Comment: @Mathias711 already tried df.plot.hist(raining) but its wrong

Comment: `raining` is your DataFrame now, so try `raining.plot()`

Comment: @Mathias711 raining is an array, not a dataframe...

Comment: Either remove the `.values`, or do something with `pyplot.hist(raining)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103848/discussion-between-user3393463-and-mathias711).

Comment: could you post a sample of your data frame?

Comment: if you define `raining = df[df.rain ==1][['ENTRIESn_hourly']]`, then raining is a data frame that you can plot using `raining.plot()`  or `raining.hist()`

Answer (score 0):

When you extract values from the dataframe it ceases to be a dataframe object, so it no longer has the .hist() function. In your case you could do:

```
raining = df[df.rain ==1][['ENTRIESn_hourly']]

#note that you do not have to specify the column again, 
#as you have already assigned it to the raining variable.

raining.hist()
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
df[df.rain ==1].hist(columns = 'ENTRIESn_hourly')    
df[df.rain ==0].hist(columns = 'ENTRIESn_hourly')
```